# Javascript if condition on boolean

Tags: javascript

Can you explain why the if condition doesn't work without the eval function:

```
var myBoolean= document.getElementById("someBoolean").value;  //This is a 'false'

if(myBoolean)
{ 
  alert(Your boolean is True);  //This condition always getting executed even though myBoolean is false;
}

if(eval(myBoolean))
{
 alert("You will never see this alert bcoz boolean is false");
}
```

Comment: How does `document.getElementById("someBoolean");` return `'false'`?

Comment: Hi Rocket, Thats an input field with false as the value.

Comment: `document.getElementById("someBoolean");` returns a DOM element (or `null`).  To get the value you'd have to do `document.getElementById("someBoolean").value;`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Javascript the following values are treated as `false` for conditionals:

- `false`
- `null`
- `undefined`
- The empty string `''`
- The number `0`
- The number `NaN`

Everything else is treated as `true`.

`'false'` is none of the above, so it's `true`.

Answer (score 5):

The string `'false'` evaluates to the boolean `true`

Comment: document.getElementById("someBoolean") does not return 'false' if the element is present in the html it return the element and that evaluates to true

Comment: @user1052591: Strings in JavaScript convert to `true` unless they are empty (`''`).

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com: It does evaluate to the `String` `'false'`. He's getting the value of the element, not the element itself. Look, he's using `.value` but he should be using `.val()` instead.

Comment: @JZ11 the question was updated, the original question did not have `.value`

Comment: @Davy8 Well I didn't see that it was edited. Regardless, his comment says he's expecting the String `'false'`. If I was more careful I would have told him to use `.val()` but regardless, the point of the question is that a non-empty String evaluates to the boolean `true`

Comment: @JZ11 You are absolutely correct and I upvoted your answer, but as the question was originally asked without .value or .val() (which may not be a good choice without jQuery or another lib that uses that function) it would have returned null or an element (which if it was an element would evaluate to true inside his if statement if it was present in the dom), thx!

Comment: Sorry folks I missed out the '.value'

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com Yes I guess you're right in that sense. But I think it's pretty obvious what the OP intended even if he forgot to add the .value function. Again, the point of the question that the OP was confused about isn't the point you're trying to make, in my opinion.

Comment: I can only go by what he originally posted and we was only gathering an element, I try not to assume anything ask good questions to get good answers :)

Comment: Right, what he also originally posted was the comment that he was expect the String. So clearly, we all know his intentions and that he was confused why "false" was evaluating to true. I think the best answer would have been to point out that he forgot to use `.value` and explain the truthiness of a String.

Answer (score 2):

This is because it's not actually a boolean, it's a the string `'false'`.  When you convert a string to a boolean, `''` is `false` and anything else is `true`.

You check if it's equal to the string `'false'` (or `'true'`) or not.

```
var myBoolean = 'false'; // (string)
myBoolean = myBoolean !== 'false'; //false (boolean)
```

Comment: var myBoolean = document.getElementById("someBoolean"); Will never equal 'false' as a string or boolean false. It will === null or true as it will eval as an dom element

Comment: @TimWickstrom.com: Yeah, I realized that, that's why I changed my answer, and also pointed it out to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

'false' == true, crazily enough because of JavaScript's implicit type coercion.  Check out these other examples from [Crockford's The Elements of JavaScript Style](http://javascript.crockford.com/style2.html).

> '' == '0' // false
> 0 == '' // true
>
> 0 == '0' // true
>
> false == 'false' // false
> false == '0' // true
>
> false == undefined // false
> false == null // false
>
> null == undefined
> // true
>
> ' \t\r\n ' == 0 // true

You could solve this particular problem by changing your code to something like

```
var myBoolean = document.getElementById("someBoolean").value === "true"
```

Also, it is almost always better to use !! and === rather than ! and ==

Comment: Hi Alex, So doing it the eval(myBoolean) is correct or there is a best/better solution.

Comment: As I said in my answer I would go with 
var myBoolean = document.getElementById("someBoolean").value === "true" or some variation.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("someBoolean") does not return a boolean true/false it returns an element or undefined / null

you could reverse your logic and get the expected result:

```
    if(!myBoolean)
    { 
      alert('This element does not exist');
    }

    if(!eval(myBoolean))
    {
     alert("Do not know why you would ever want to do this");
// you could do typeof() 
    }
```

Comment: The question was updated so this answer is no longer relevant

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myBoolean= document.getElementById("someBoolean").value;  //This is a 'false'

if(myBoolean != "false")
{ 
  alert(Your boolean is True);  //This condition always getting executed even though myBoolean is false;
}
```

Like others have said, a string isn't a boolean value, so using it as though it was will give you a logical error.

Answer (score -1):

A string IS a boolean truth value according to ECMA

```
var a = ""<br/>
a&&false //-> false<br/>
a||false //-> "" (truthy)<br/>
```

Comment: Well 4 years after the discussion started might mean that versions of ECMA / JavaScript and the language rules changed, but empty string truthy? I read question and accepted answer as that there was a misconception starting with varaible names, where - as in some programming languages - the string `'false'` is considered like a true value in boolean contexts. `whatever && false` should always be false regardless of `whatever` brings to the table, and yes, the effective value of `""||false` may be `""`, but I would understand this as "false" in a boolean context.

Comment: This answer does not provide anything the other answers to the question already have provided.